# Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:new)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting this error when I run rspec:

> Failures:
>
> 1) AccountsController POST :create an account that already exists renders the :new template
>        Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:new)
>          **expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>**
>        # ./spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb:131:in `block (4 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.26832 seconds
>   34 examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb:128 # AccountsController POST :create an account that already exists renders the :new template

I verify that my code is written correctly by running it in the rails console. And true enough, it renders the :new template and even returns a 200. I do this by using the app object in the rails console. The output is below:

```
Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-26 21:18:06 -0700
Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"account"=>{"name"=>"name", "description"=>"desc", "opening_balance"=>"1.0"}}
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Account Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."name" = 'name' LIMIT 1
 [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
**Rendered accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)**
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 32.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
 => 200
```

This creates the same account twice. I expect that, it will fail and then redirect to :new template. The rspec code is here:

```
  context 'an account that already exists' do

     it 'renders the :new template' do
       call_post_create_verb
       call_post_create_verb
       **expect(response).to render_template(:new)**
     end

   end
```

Look in the else condition and you will find where I render :new. The controller code is here:

```
def ceate
   @account = Account.new(account_params)
   if @account.save
     redirect_to @account
   else
     **render :new**
   end
end
```

This is my setup:
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
rails (4.0.3)
rspec-rails (2.14.1)

Comment: are you really calling create twice in your spec?

Comment: we'd need to see some more context, like the actual contents of the spec (what is `call_post_create_verb`?)

Comment: clear the test log and run failing spec. Check the test log since it may point out something new info.

Answer (score 1):

```
let(:call_post_create_verb) { post :create, account: valid_info }
```

Originally to simulate the creating the same account twice, I simply called it twice. It should work, but it refused to. So instead of calling it twice, I changed the first call to:

```
Account.create valid_info
```

So I'm creating it first in the model, and then calling the 'post create' to create an account with the same info again which should surely fail because I'm validating for uniqueness in the name property.

After doing this, it finally worked.

Comment: This is because Rspec's `let` blocks cache the result, so the first time it's called you actually do the post, the second time it's called you just get a reference to the result and don't actually make a second request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views) to spec. RSpec renders nothing by default - that is why you get "expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>"

```
context 'an account that already exists' do

  render_views

  it 'renders the :new template' do
    call_post_create_verb
    call_post_create_verb
    **expect(response).to render_template(:new)**
  end
```

end

Comment: render_views is not the answer. I just tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: and check what do you have in `response.body` at the end of test? Do you have empty string in it or some rendered partial "new"?